# Beamer metropolis theme - add image to section page

Tags: beamer, graphics, beamer-metropolis

Is there a way to easily add an image to a section slide in the Metropolis theme for beamer?

Basically, I have this using `\section{Selection Bias}`:

[image]

And want this:

[image]

I found a related answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338362/including-an-image-on-the-section-title-page-of-beamer), but it seems like there might be a more efficient way to do this without `renew`ing the command every time, and I'd rather not rebuild the title part because I like having the indicator bar, etc.

Comment: Please, can you add your complete code? This way it's easier to help you.

Comment: Yes, sorry @Sebastiano. The code in the answer is sufficient to run, but next time I'll include from the start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't like the renewcommand, you could pass the image name as optional argument to the section page template.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

%%% Section page template with picture

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{section page}{mytheme}[1][]{
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{22em}
    \raggedright
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{section title}
    \usebeamerfont{section title}
    \insertsectionhead\\[-1ex]
    \usebeamertemplate*{progress bar in section page}
    \par
    \ifx\insertsubsectionhead\@empty\else%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection title}%
      \usebeamerfont{subsection title}%
      \insertsubsectionhead
    \fi
    \vskip0.5cm
    \ifstrempty{#1}{}{%
        \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{#1}%
    }
  \end{minipage}
  \par
  \vspace{\baselineskip}
}
\makeatother

%%% Define a command to include picture in section, 
%%% make section, and revert to old template

\newcommand{\sectionpic}[2]{
   \setbeamertemplate{section page}[mytheme][#2]
   \section{#1}
   \setbeamertemplate{section page}[mytheme]
}

%%% Document

\begin{document}

\section{normal}    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\sectionpic{image}{example-image}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @samcarter! Works great. I just added a short command, `sectionpic`, to insert a photo section and revert the template in a single command, so you don't have to manually do this every time.

Comment: Is there a way to change the image size locally? I mean not all images work well with .4\textwidth.